# Unable to AES_DECRYPT after AES_ENCRYPT in mysql

Tags: mysql, encryption

I created user table

```
CREATE  TABLE `user` (
`id` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`first_name` VARBINARY(100) NULL ,
`address` VARBINARY(200) NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_general_ci;
```

I inserted one row:

```
INSERT into user (first_name, address) VALUES (AES_ENCRYPT('Obama', 'usa2010'),AES_ENCRYPT('Obama', 'usa2010'));
```

To select this row i used:

```
SELECT AES_DECRYPT(first_name, 'usa2010'), AES_DECRYPT(address, 'usa2010') from user;
```

I am getting the following result.What i need to do see my data.No data is visible for me.

[image: I am unable to see my data]

Comment: working here http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/31323/2

Comment: But why i am getting like that.Is there any reason

Comment: what version of mysql you are using?

Comment: Is there any secured way to encrypt my data without any key.

Comment: try casting, `CAST(AES_DECRYPT(first_name, 'usa2010') AS CHAR(50))` and see if it works.

Comment: Yes it is working now.Thanks u what is the reason

Comment: But when i use select * from user; how i can use CAST

Comment: i have no idea what's the reason sorry. anyway, try: `select *, CAST(AES_DECRYPT(first_name, 'usa2010') AS CHAR(50)) first_name_decrypt from user` and use `first_name_decrypt` instead of `first_name`.

Comment: Is there any way to encrypt data without using key

Comment: I am not using mysql to encrypt the data. I do it in thge application level `:)`

Comment: ok.thanks  for spending your time

Answer (score 39, accepted):

According to the Manual:

> AES_ENCRYPT() encrypts a string and returns a binary string. 
>   **AES_DECRYPT() decrypts the encrypted string and returns the original string**.

- [MySQL 5.1 Doc: AES_ENCRYPT() / AES_DECRYPT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/encryption-functions.html#function_aes-encrypt)

I don't know why it is still returning a binary string in your case. Anyway, try this:

```
SELECT *, 
       CAST(AES_DECRYPT(first_name, 'usa2010') AS CHAR(50)) first_name_decrypt 
FROM   user
```

And use `first_name_decrypt` instead of `first_name`.

Comment: Does the same on our server (5.5)

Comment: Caution:  `(50)` may work for this example, but not be long enough for others.

Answer (score 16):

From mysql command line client there is no need to use `CAST`:

```
mysql> SELECT AES_DECRYPT(AES_ENCRYPT('admin','abc'),'abc');

+-----------------------------------------------+
| AES_DECRYPT(AES_ENCRYPT('admin','abc'),'abc') |
+-----------------------------------------------+
| admin                                         |
+-----------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT CAST(AES_DECRYPT(AES_ENCRYPT('admin','abc'),'abc') AS CHAR (50));

+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| CAST(AES_DECRYPT(AES_ENCRYPT('admin','abc'),'abc') AS CHAR (50)) |
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| admin                                                            |
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
```

As you can see using cast in command line is little bit slower. But I have noticed that if you use some tools like phpmyadmin, then you need to use `CAST`, otherwise result will be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, turns out I had my column data type set as VARCHAR when I encrypted the data and when I switched over to MEDIUMTEXT, it wouldn't return anything else than a BLOB.

Quoting a part from dev.mysql:

> Many encryption and compression functions return strings for which the result might contain arbitrary byte values. If you want to store these results, use a column with a VARBINARY or BLOB binary string data type. This will avoid potential problems with trailing space removal or character set conversion that would change data values, such as may occur if you use a nonbinary string data type (CHAR, VARCHAR, TEXT).

Switching to a supported column type worked for me.

Answer (score -3):

```
if (isset($_POST['user_name']) and isset($_POST['user_password'])){

$user_name = $_POST['user_name'];
$user_password = $_POST['user_password'];


$query = "SELECT * FROM `user_tbl` WHERE user_name='$user_name' and AES_DECRYPT(user_password , '@ert') = '$user_password'";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
```

Comment: code without an explanation is not really very useful. Please explain what are the important parts, and why it answers the question.

Comment: Additionally, that code is widely open to SQL injections. One should definitely not use it anywhere