# Check String is encrypted in php

Tags: php, encryption

I have a form that on it, I've got information from database. Now I want to check just a record on it and it is : **Is it possible that I check the string value of that field and if it was encrypted or not**, **for response I return true or false**!!
How can I solve this issue??

Comment: What do you mean by encrypted? With what function?

Comment: I think It will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16556375/how-to-use-aes-encrypt-and-aes-decrypt-in-mysql

Comment: SELECT  IF(CAST(AES_DECRYPT(AES_ENCRYPT(col_name,''),'') as char)=col_name,'true','false') from tbl_name;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the encrypted of decrypted of the value is equivalent  to the input text

Answer (score 0):

To check if it's encrypted you need the key that has encrypted the value.

```
SELECT if(AES_DECRYPT(`cloumn`, 'encyrption key...') is null, 'false','true') FROM `table`
```

If you don't have the key you could maybe try testing a certain language signature (the amount of occurences in the string of certain characters). The type of encryption would be rather difficult to detect.