# Mysql AES_DECRYPT(AES_ENCRYPT())

Tags: mysql, encryption, aes

I have a problem with mysql encryption, on a mysql server 5.5.38

If I do :

```
 SELECT AES_DECRYPT(AES_ENCRYPT("test", "123"), "123");
```

the result is 74657374

I saw in the mysql doc that DECODE() and ENCODE() are deprecated and that we are encouraged to use AES functions :

> The ENCODE() and DECODE() functions are deprecated in MySQL 5.7, will be removed in a future MySQL release, and should no longer be used. Consider using AES_ENCRYPT() and AES_DECRYPT() instead.

Note : when I use SELECT DECODE(ENCODE("test", "123"), "123"), the result is the same : 74657374

Comment: I believe an AES encryption key is meant to be 32 characters long

Comment: So, what's the problem exactly?

Comment: `74657374` looks like the ascii/hex characters for "test": 74-65-73-74.  How are you running this query/displaying the results?  It looks like your data is being cast into a different format.

Comment: Using a 32 character long key does the same : 
     SELECT AES_DECRYPT(AES_ENCRYPT("test", "12345678901234567890123456789011"), "12345678901234567890123456789011");

Comment: For the ascii/hex format, yes, it's surely involved in the problem, but I can't figure out where.

Answer (score 2):

Ok I have my answer :

```
SELECT CAST(AES_DECRYPT(AES_ENCRYPT('test admin','1234'),'1234') AS CHAR (50))
```

It was a cast issue.

Explanations here : 
    [How to use AES_ENCRYPT and AES_DECRYPT in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16556375/how-to-use-aes-encrypt-and-aes-decrypt-in-mysql?rq=1)

Comment: So this is a duplicate then. No need to post an answer. You should able so see a button above your question to confirm that that is a duplicate.

Comment: You're totally right. I'm using stack for years but some of the features and best practices are still weird for me. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

It's working correctly.

74657374 is a Hexidecimal representation of the string 'test':

```
74 = t
65 = e
73 = s
74 = t
```

Try using `unhex`:

`SELECT UNHEX(AES_DECRYPT(AES_ENCRYPT("test", "123"), "123"));`

Comment: I thought it was the solution, but no, the UNHEX query returns NULL.