# Using AES_ENCRYPT AND AES_DECRYPT I don't get returning data

Tags: php, mysql, aes, password-encryption

I'm trying to use **AES_ENCRYPT** AND **AES_DECRYPT**, I do get a string of random characters in the MYSQL data field but can't return anything with the AES_DECRYPT

My table field for password is setup as **VARBINARY, 600 Length**.

**ADDING INTO THE DATABASE I HAVE:**

```
mysqli_select_db( $connection , $databaseName );
$request = '
    UPDATE person
    SET firstName = AES_ENCRYPT("Fred","key123")
    WHERE ID="34"';
$result = mysqli_query( $connection , $request );
```

**SELECTING FROM THE DATABASE I HAVE:**

```
mysqli_select_db( $connection , $databaseName );
$request = "SELECT AES_DECRYPT(firstName, 'key123') FROM account WHERE ID = 34";    
$result2 = mysqli_query($connection , $request);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2);
$firstName = $row['firstName'];

echo $firstName;
```

This just returns nothing. Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: You should never encrypt your user's passwords. You need to use hashing instead with some strong ones being PBKDF2, bcrypt, scrypt and Argon2. Since hash functions are one-way function, you won't be able to "decrypt" the hashes. In order to authenticate your user, you can run the password through the hash function again in order to compare with the hash that is stored in the database. See more: [How to securely hash passwords?](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/211/45523)

Comment: you entered "key123" but trying to retrieve "123". by *"just returns nothing"*, I don't see where you're echoing anything.

Comment: *"ADDING INTO THE DATABASE I HAVE"* - that's not "adding", it's "updating". Adding is "INSERT INTO...". how do you know it even updated successfully? Your question's unclear.

Comment: @ Artjom B The use of password is just an example, I plan on hashing all passwords.

@Fred -ii- I have tried changing the salt to both key123 still returns nothing, also I have checked the MYSQL database as can see the data in the field.

Anymore ideas?

Comment: see if this answer helps http://stackoverflow.com/a/16556522/

Comment: you'll need to clarify what you mean by *"This just returns nothing"*. Your question doesn't show us if you're echoing anything. check for errors also on your query http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: This doesn't work unless I have to encrypt the data different?

$request = "SELECT CAST(AES_DECRYPT(password, 'key123') AS CHAR(50)) FROM account_decrypt WHERE ID = 42";

Comment: I'm comparing $password to the $enteredPassword, this is just an example I know passwords need to be hashed.

Comment: I have updated the question code, see if that makes more sense?

Answer (score 0):

In the update query you use ID as a string and in the SELECT query it is used as an int, try to fix this.
You should change the select to `WHERE ID = "34"`

Comment: I have updated the question code to make a little more sense.

Comment: it still looks to me like the string vs int issue

Answer (score 0):

You are working on two different tables.
You are updating the 'person' table. Then, you are selecting from the 'account' table.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$request = "SELECT AES_DECRYPT(firstName, 'key123') FROM account WHERE ID = 34";
```

to this:

```
$request = `SELECT AES_DECRYPT(firstName, 'key123') FROM person WHERE ID = "34"`;
```

Answer (score -1):

**Try this:**

**`SELECT AES_DECRYPT(AES_ENCRYPT('firstName','mykeystring')FROM account WHERE ID = 34";`**

**Explanation:**

I read online that the above sql statement decrypts the encrypted string 'firstName' using mykeystring and returns the original string firstName.

Comment: Do you think that this will fix this the problem? Then you should add an explanation instead of _Try this:_. Otherwise you should add this as comment.

Comment: Hey Muhammad,
I have tried this but just get a error return of:
Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in ...

Comment: Where it says '$result2 = mysqli_query($connection , $request)' replace it with '$result2 = mysqli_query($connection , $request) or die (mysqli_error($connection));

Comment: what is proposed hasn't even been tested (parenthesis missing, "I read online", not working in my environment)