# MYSQL AES DECRYPT, result is null?

Tags: mysql, encryption

```
create table usuario (
nombre varchar(10),
contraseña varchar(10)
);

INSERT INTO usuario 
VALUES ('manuel', AES_ENCRYPT('conejo seco', '10')
);

INSERT INTO usuario VALUES (
'conejo','1234567890'
);

select * from usuario;
```

Perfect, the user manuel contraseña is encrypted, now to decryption

```
SELECT AES_DECRYPT(contraseña, '10') FROM usuario WHERE nombre = 'manuel';
```

Hm? null? oh well, lets see if is unlocked.

```
select * from usuario;
```

Nope, still encrypted.

---

Thats how it went, how i can "unlock" the encrypted user "contraseña"? and see it when i call it with a select after i use decrypt.

Edit:

```
update usuario set contraseña = AES_DECRYPT(contraseña, '10') WHERE nombre = 'manuel';
```

result is null.

```
SELECT *, CAST(AES_DECRYPT(contraseña, '10') AS CHAR(50)) contraseña_decrypt FROM usuario where nombre = 'manuel';
```

result is null.

```
SELECT contraseña = AES_DECRYPT(contraseña, '10') FROM usuario WHERE nombre = 'manuel';
```

result is null.

Comment: You have to store the decrypted value back in your table. ATM you are just calculating it but this is temporary...

Comment: store it back? i dont understand.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use AES\_ENCRYPT and AES\_DECRYPT in mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16556375/how-to-use-aes-encrypt-and-aes-decrypt-in-mysql)

Comment: Indeed, looks like what i am looking, let me try it, if i understand it and make it work, i will delete this one, else you are free to show me how it will work with my current example.

Comment: nope, my brain is unable to understand the sintax, the times i can make it work the result is still null.

Answer (score 0):

You try to store the output of [AES_ENCRYPT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/encryption-functions.html#function_aes-encrypt), which is binary, into a `varchar(10)` column (which is text). This is likely to corrupt your data. Try instead one of the [binary types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/binary-varbinary.html). To do so replace this:

```
create table usuario (
  nombre varchar(10),
  contraseña varchar(10)
);
```

... with e.g. this:

```
create table usuario (
  nombre varchar(10),
  contraseña varbinary(500)
);
```

Comment: Still result is null even when setting it as binary.

Comment: You are right, took me a while to find it, but it was that way.

Comment: The updated question doesn't try my suggested fix. I've updated my answer and tried to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table usuario (nombre varchar(10), contraseña varbinary(18));

INSERT INTO usuario VALUES ('manuel', AES_ENCRYPT('ConejoSeco', '10'));
INSERT INTO usuario VALUES ('conejo','1234567890');

select * from usuario;
```

So VARCHAR(10) should be converted to  VARBINARY(18) minimum,  if AES_DECRYPT() detects invalid data or incorrect padding, it will return NULL. But it is also possible for AES_DECRYPT() to return a non-NULL value (possibly garbage) if the input data or the key is invalid.

why 18?

So if your address field structure is= VARCHAR(10) ; //10 length of varchar, Then before your encryption it should be converted 16 * ((10/ 16) + 1) = 16 * (0.625 + 1) = 16 * 1.625 = 17.625

The answer was outside of stackoveflow, but it was an answer from a previous question done in stackoverflow.

outside:
http://thinkdiff.net/mysql/encrypt-mysql-data-using-aes-techniques/

stackoverflow:
[How to use AES_ENCRYPT and AES_DECRYPT in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16556375/how-to-use-aes-encrypt-and-aes-decrypt-in-mysql)