# Using AES_ENCRYPT in Prepared Statement with Bind Variables

Tags: php, mysqli, aes

Wanting to encrypt a particular data variable but keep getting  "PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function AES_ENCRYPT()..."

Research has lead me to a hint that it's using PHP instead of MySQL?

```
$key="xyz";

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($mysqli, "INSERT INTO details (FirstName, LastName, EncryptThis) VALUES (?,?,?)");

if ($stmt === false) {
        trigger_error('Statement failed! ' . htmlspecialchars(mysqli_error($mysqli)), E_USER_ERROR);
    }                      

$bind = mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $FirstName, $LastName,  AES_ENCRYPT('$EncryptThis','$key'));

        if ($bind === false) {
        trigger_error('Bind param failed!', E_USER_ERROR);
    }                  

$exec = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

Am using varbinary in the DB...

Have tried various uses of

```
AES_ENCRYPT('$EncryptThis','$key')
```

EG

```
AES_ENCRYPT($EncryptThis,$key)
```

etc etc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use AES\_ENCRYPT and AES\_DECRYPT in mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16556375/how-to-use-aes-encrypt-and-aes-decrypt-in-mysql)

Comment: Thx @rjdown, found this during research...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL is expecting *values* to be be passed as bind parameters. Not names of functions or other SQL expressions. Just *values*.

If you want to invoke the MySQL AES_ENCRYPT function, that needs to be appear as part of the SQL text (the string prepared as a SQL statement). The name of the function can't be passed as a part of a bind parameter.

Like this:

```
 "INSERT ... VALUES ( ? , ? , AES_ENCRYPT( ? , ? ) )" 

 mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssss", $FirstName, $LastName, $EncryptThis, $key);
```

Comment: Have updated - no PHP Fatal error, except now a blank value shown in DB column..  No errors in error_log. I did not add an extra column in the DB for $key? Should INSERT include the key?

Comment: No - all good.  My poor use of quotes. Thank you @spencer7593