# How can I store the configuration/properties file in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have a scenario where I need to store the configuration/properties file in MySql and use it further in the project, Does a simple configuration table like below makes sense or any other suggestions to improve this?

I have to put other mysql db configuration in a table, I approached in a simple way as,

creating table named config:

```
create table config(host varchar(50),
                    user varchar(30),
                    password varchar(30),
                    db varchar(30),
                    charset varchar(20),
                    cursorclass varchar(30) );
```

and inserting the respective `values` to `config`

I thought some fields would be mandatory ,so simply would add a `NOTNULL`

Is there a better way to manage the same configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be best if you can encrypt your sensitive information because in the case of hacking of this master table no one can reach to your other databases easily. So my suggestions are to make it a little bit secure and security should be at the pear ( lock + key = open door ) level.

Ref: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_aes-encrypt

Comment: I understand but how could I come up with, any example please?

Comment: In mysql, you can encrypt the data by using yours on salt. Ref: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_aes-encrypt

Comment: This is very helpful sir, so I can just encrypt with the same table and that is secured?

Comment: Yes, but your key should not static, it should be dynamic by storing it to any variable.

Comment: Please could you elaborate or this can be achieved as?

Comment: This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16556375/how-to-use-aes-encrypt-and-aes-decrypt-in-mysql

Comment: If still want more help then let me know.

Comment: Sure, I will implement this and if I get stuck anywhere I will ask you mate